# Why are my embedded code blocks not being evaluated?

Tags: css, asp.net

I am attempting to use embedded code blocks in my ASP.NET user control .ascx file to try to set the width and height of the control from public properties of the control.  I have been able to do this in the past on different projects, but for some reason it is not working now.  I can do this in the code behind if I'd like, but why are the code blocks not being evaluated?  I noticed they get evaluated when I don't include runat="server" in the tag.

.ascx code:

```
div id="PopupWindow" class="ModalWindow" 
        style="width: <%= Width.ToString() %>; height: <%= Height.ToString() %>;" runat="server" ></div>
```

css error in the inspector:

```
element {

    width: <% Width.ToString() %>;
    height: <% Height.ToString() %>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Introduction to ASP.NET inline expressions in the .NET Framework](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976112/introduction-to-asp-net-inline-expressions-in-the-net-framework):

> Remember that the displaying expression cannot be used in the attributes of server controls. This is because the .NET Framework directly compiles the whole expression instead of the displaying content as the value to the attribute.

Maybe it helps if you view server controls (elements created with `runat="server"`) as a kind of embedded code blocks too. So then any code blocks inside would be nested server side code, and that doesn't work!

So, possible solutions, as you already mentioned, are to remove `runat="server"`, or to handle things on the server and put the sizes in from there.